# Tenancy, error usando sanctum retorna 405 metodo no permitido

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, postman

Estoy teniendo un problema con obtener la data de modelos, esto me pasa unicamente cuando cambio las rutas al middleware de sanctum. Resulta que si puedo hacer  a tenant-1/login y a su vez generar el token para el usuario del inquilino, pero al acceder a la ruta tenant-1/productos que la tenngo dentro del auth:sanctum ya me genera error, me dice que el metodo get no es soportado.

he realizado varias pruebas pero no se si configure algo mal en el  proceso, comparto como tengo los archivos configurado.

mi archivo en routes/tenant/api.php

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Controllers\ProfileInformationController;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use App\Models\Tenant\Product;
use Inertia\Inertia;


Route::post('/login', [AuthController::class, "login"]);
Route::post('/register', [AuthController::class, "register"]);

Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function () {
    Route::post('/logout', [AuthController::class, "logout"]);
    Route::resource("books", BookController::class)->except("create", "show");
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
        return $request->user();
    });

    Route::put("/user/profile-information", [ProfileInformationController::class, "update"]);

    Route::get('/productos', function(string $tenant){
        $products = Product::all();
        dd($products);
     });


});
```

mi archivo de tenancy ConfigureTenantRoutes.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Tenancy\Affects\Routes\Events\ConfigureRoutes;


class ConfigureTenantRoutes
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    public function handle(ConfigureRoutes $event)
    {

        if ($event->event->tenant) {
            $event
                ->flush()
                ->fromFile(
                    ["middleware" => ["web"]],
                    base_path("routes/tenant/web.php")
                )
                ->fromFile(
                    ['prefix' => '{tenant}'],
                    base_path("routes/tenant/api.php")
                );
        }
    }
}
```

asi tengo el auth.php de laravel

```
<?php

return [

    'defaults' => [
        'guard' => 'web',
        'passwords' => 'users',
    ],

   'guards' => [

        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'tenant',
        ],

        'web' => [
            'driver' => 'session',
            'provider' => 'users',
        ],

        'api' => [
            'driver' => 'token',
            'provider' => 'users',
            'hash' => false,
        ],
    ],

    'providers' => [
        'tenant' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\Tenant\UserTenant::class,
        ], 
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ], 
 
        // 'users' => [
        //     'driver' => 'database',
        //     'table' => 'users',
        // ],
    ],

    'passwords' => [
        'users' => [
            'provider' => 'users',
            'table' => 'password_resets',
            'expire' => 60,
            'throttle' => 60,
        ],
    ],

    'password_timeout' => 10800,

];
```

en las imagenes tambien muestro el error que recibo al realizar la prueba en postman.

terminando por retornarme que el metodo get no esta permitido, probe para salir de dudas utilizar resource y aun asi me retorna el mismo error.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Los token en Laravel se usan a través de las cabeceras de la petición, es decir van en la propiedad `Authorization` y seguido de `Bearer` junto al token que Laravel te da. Muestra cómo estás enviado ese token y consultándolo dentro de tu grupo de rutas en sanctum. Es difícil darte una ayuda **si nos muestras un ejemplo que SÍ te funciona**

Comment: realice pruebas tanto en el headers de postman como en el Authorization y el token> Bearer 20|uaPvjqmQVHITvVzM3isNkBB8ewSx6vmHHFlofvwz asi como tambien en el tabs Authorization colocarndo tambien el token, en ninguno de los casos me pasa, me retorna el mismo error

Comment: ¿Seguiste todos los pasos de la documentación de [Laravel Sanctum](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum)?

Comment: Hace tiempo realize una pregunta "parecida", ya que en realidad al utilizar laravel sanctum, tus rutas deberian estar en `api.php` y no en `web.php` https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/441244

Comment: Por otra parte, no veo la ruta `tenant-1/productos`, si "tenant-1" es una variable, no deberia ser `productos/{variable}`?

Comment: he actualizado mi consulta con codigo y tambien imagenes para entregar mas informacion y detalles...